# Detect a posts publishdate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the actual date that is shown as the publishdate at the wall.

Facebook allows a pageadmin to manipulate the publishdate of a post.

Problem is that I can't get this date from any field.

Maybe you know it :)

Comment: No created_time on any field? What API you're using? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed?

Comment: CreationTime is the time when the post was created.

Comment: i can see created_time on http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed, so, what's the problem?

Comment: CreatedTime is wrong.. try to change the time of the post and nothing happens to the field.

Comment: "updated_time" key also here, you can get this field, right?

Comment: Not working. Just test it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I can get both "created_time" and "updated_time" fields on http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=6815841748%2Ffeed

[image]

Comment: Yes and now change the date of the post.

Comment: So, if you change the date of your post, the 'update_time' value wouldn't update, is that your exact problem?